# Why does yawning distort headphone music?

Tags: acoustics, biophysics, biology

During deep and prolonged yawning, I noticed the music tonality is distorted: the pitch becomes slightly lower.

Why?

Comment: A first idea: when you tense the muscles, there is likely a change in tension in the tympanic membrane too. That ought to change its frequency response.

Comment: I do not even ear....

Answer (score 2):

When you yawn the shape of the ear canal changes.

(I know that for sure because I have a set of fitted hearing protection plugs. For fitting the ear canal is injection filled with a goo that loses its fluidity in minutes. That serves as a template to create the daily use earplugs. The plugs are a perfect fit, but not at all when I yawn.)

When the shape of the ear canal changes it resonant properties change. Compare wistling: change the position of your tongue and the pitch changes, because the resonant properties of your mouth cavity are changed.

The change in resonant properties of the ear canal affects the "color" of the music. The change in resonant properties doesn't change the acutal pitch, but it does shift the pattern of which harmonics (that the music consists of) are selectively amplified.

This may explain why in your subjective experience the pitch changes.

A more daring hypothesis would be that during yawning the mechanical properties of the cochlea are changed. The cochlea is a rolled up structure that does the conversion of mechanical transmission of vibration to neurons signaling the auditory part of the brain.

The lowest pitched sounds the human ear can hear trigger neurons at the start of the cochlea, the highest pitched sounds trigger neurons at the far end of the cochlea. It's a distribution over the length of the cochlea; every frequency has a specific area where it triggers neurons.

It could be, I don't know, that during yawning some push/pull from surrounding tissue changes the mechanical properties of the cochlea slightly, causing a shift in which neurons are triggered to send signals. Your perception then is a change of the pitch of the music.

Comment: In addation to this, yawning also affects the Eustachian tube.

Answer (score 0):

In patients with *somatic tinnitus*, the pitch and loudness of the ringing in their ears that they experience can be modulated by clenching their jaw muscles or their neck muscles. In the form of tinnitus I suffer from, I can shift the pitch down by opening my jaw while resisting the jaw movement with my hand.

My audiologist suggests that this is because the auditory nerve crosses over the nerves that connect to the jaw muscles and that in some people, "crosstalk" occurs: nerve signals sent to the jaw can affect hearing response in this way.